# Search Form Not searching

Tags: html, forms, search

Ive got a knowledgebase and a bunch of test articles setup, when i use the search function nothing actually searches in the search bar after i search `http://Example.com/Knowledge.html?s=Search+Test#`

and it just doesn't search the page doesn't go no where

here is the code i think it might be!

```
<!-- Start of Search Wrapper -->
<div class="search-area-wrapper">
    <div class="search-area container">
        <h3 class="search-header">Have a Question?</h3>
        <p class="search-tag-line">If you have any question you can ask below or enter what you are looking for!</p>

        <form id="search-form" class="search-form clearfix" method="get" action="#" autocomplete="off">
            <input class="search-term required" type="text" id="s" name="s" placeholder="Type your search terms here" title="* Please enter a search term!" />
            <input class="search-btn" type="submit" value="Search" />
            <div id="search-error-container"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

if its not that! i can send the hole HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should have action="#" it it possible that you grabbed this from an example and forgot to change a couple of things. That should equal whatever script is actually doing the searching.

Comment: hm possibly im not really sure what script is doing to editing though